# Need help to rewrite PHP function

Tags: php, regex

I have a function that parses text form posts and if there's a link in the post it'll redirect the link to a page that warns a users about external link before they click it.

```
function url2link($txt) {
     $setUrl = preg_replace("/(http:\/\/|(www\.))(([^\s<]{4,68})[^\s<]*)/", '<a href="/link/$2$3" rel="nofollow">$2$4</a>', $txt);
     return $setUrl;
}
```

I need to modify this function by adding a check for domain in the link. If the link is from my own domain, just convert it into clickable link like this:

```
$setUrl = preg_replace("/(http:\/\/|(www\.))(([^\s<]{4,68})[^\s<]*)/", '<a href="http://$2$3" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">$2$4</a>', $txt);
```

but if it is a link to an external domain -- make a link point to a warning page (top example).

I am sort of stuck here because I have no idea how to add this check. There could be multiple links in a post, some may have local, some external links and some a mix.

Comment: Please clarify - is this text being pulled from a large block of inline text (such as a textarea) in which multiple urls may be encountered?  Or is there a dedicated form field for URLs, perhaps comma separated or such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), then you can process the matches to decide whether it's your own domain or some other.

Comment: Someone mentioned it earlier but I could not figure out how to apply this solution...

Comment: Yes, I just did it again, but I suppose the concept is too different for me to grasp it. I understand that it does not replace like preg_replace but I'm still unclear what to do with it.

Comment: I re-wrote my function but it does not seem to work. I posted it here in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, as it turned out preg_replace_callback was exactly what I needed in this case. php.net documentation sucks. I found another article that made it clear what it is and how it works. I modified my function but it doesn't work... What am I missing?

```
function url2link($txt) {

$checkDomain = preg_replace_callback('/(http:\/\/|(www\.))(([^\s<]{4,68})[^\s<]*)/', 'linkDomain', $txt);

   function linkDomain($matches) {

    $host =  parse_url($matches[0], PHP_URL_HOST);
    $host =  ltrim($host, 'www.');

    if ($host == 'mydomain.com') {
        $setUrl = preg_replace("/(http:\/\/|(www\.))(([^\s<]{4,68})[^\s<]*)/", '<a href="http://$2$3">$2$4</a>', $matches[0]);
    } else {
        $setUrl = preg_replace("/(http:\/\/|(www\.))(([^\s<]{4,68})[^\s<]*)/", '<a href="/link/$2$3" rel="nofollow">$2$4</a>', $matches[0]);
    }
   }
   return $setUrl;
}
```

Comment: Why do you say php documentation sucks? It's actually one of the best resources out there. If you want something bad, take a look at facebook's. Anyway, it seems like you are trying to work still with `$txt`, don't. The match has been done, do a `print_r($matches)` in your linkDomain function and work with that.

Comment: I use php.net as a reference all the time but I just could not grasp this function. I guess for someone not formally trained as a developer. Yes, Facebook documentation has a lot of holes. Anyway, I must be doing something wrong. I can't even see any array values a by putting print_r($matches) in linkDomain($matches) function or any values for that matter. I think it's broken but not sure where.

Comment: OK, updated above. Still something is out of place -- not working.

Comment: Figured it out with someone else's help. I was putting a function within another function...